# Consider a light source moving at a high velocity. How all does relativity affect the brightness, wavelength, and other attributes?

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, time-dilation, doppler-effect

Consider a spherical light source moving at a high velocity (v=.9c) straight towards you, the observer.  How all does relativity affect the brightness, wavelength, and other attributes of the light the observer observes?

Now consider that the spherical light source is passing overhead at (v=.9c) at a distance 100 km away.  How all does relativity affect the brightness, wavelength, and other attributes of the light one might observe?

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

If light source moves towards you at 0.9C, you will see it significantly blue-shifted, even if it is a far infrared light it will be seen by you as blue. Brightness will become about 10 times larger.

If light source moves overhead, you will see it red shifted from blue to red, and it brightness will reduce by about two time. But it will be a very short moment. Before and after it will behave more like coming closer and moving away.

Comment: The first sentence of the last paragraph is quite wrong.  It's also not clearly related to the question at hand.

Comment: @WillO removed it